# Adding new values to existing mongo array

Tags: java, mongodb

My sample Mongo doc is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51fa3d516bde1ca6f017a570"),
    "digits":[
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6
    ]
}
```

I want to append digits array with some extra values.
say:

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[3];
int[] myIntArray = {7,8,9};
```

How to append myIntArray to digits array in java
my java code is:

```
BasicDBList digits=(BasicDBList) cursor.next().get("digits");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) operator for that.  You don't have to iterate over the collection to do it, you can do an update inside the database.

Written in Java, this would look something like

```
collection.update(...query expression...,
  new BasicDBObject("$push",
    new BasicDBObject("digits", value)));
```

This assumes that `value` is a single new value for the array. If you want to append all the elements of an array at once, you have to use the `$each` modifier (see above link for the details).