# Adding document under nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, postman

I need to add one more address like `address.2._id,type`,etc...:

```
{
    "address" : {
        "1" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a570f3d422c8223bac22dca"),
            "type" : "Primary",
            "street" : "58,Jones road",
            "area" : "Saidapet",
            "city" : "Chennai",
            "pincode" : "600015",
            "state" : "Tamil nadu",
            "country" : "India"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I insert a particular document under a nested document?

Comment: Which language do you use? May duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992405/adding-new-values-to-existing-mongo-array

Comment: node.js with Postman REST api

Comment: Why are you posting all your personal data on stack overflow?

Comment: Thank you people. @MattFletcher This is not my personal info dude. It is like an unknown data. Instead of looking sample data, why not we look for the solution? Stack Overflow is the open forum for solutions right?